# Servicio de Windows-timer

Tags: c#

Hola estoy creando un servicio de windows, un ejemplo quiero que se ejecute cada 5 minutos lo logro,pero mi programa dura 50 minutos ejecutandose, lo que me hace el servicio es correr los 5 minutos y despues se reinicia y no termina. De que forma puedo hacer para que termine y despues vuleva a contar los 5 minutos.

```
    this.timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1200000);  // 3000000 milliseconds = 20 min
    this.timer.Enabled = true;
    this.timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.OnTimer);
    this.timer.Start();
```

he probado con this.timer.autoreset = true pero no me funciona.

Answer (score 1):

en el evento onTimer de tu app podes utilizar stop y start para que comience de nuevo.
Ejemplo:

```
private void OnTimer(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
           //Detener antes de comenzar tarea.
            this.timer.Stop();
            //tu tarea aqui que demora 50 minutos.
           //comenzar timer de nuevo.
            this.timer.Start();

        }
```

Comment: ok, probare si me funciona de esta forma,gracias

Comment: Si me funciono muchas gracias.